# How do I create a Fluent nHibernate component mapping with data from another table

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm running into some difficulty setting up a Fluent nHibernate mapping where I'm trying to use the Component function to build up an object that with data from two related database tables.

Below is a simplified version of the database and code that outlines the basic problem I'm having.

I've got a database setup that looks similar to the following:

```
Account
  - AccountId INT (PRIMARY KEY)
  - Currency VARCHAR(3)

SubAccount
  - SubAccountId INT (PRIMARY KEY)
  - AccountId INT (FOREIGN KEY reference to Account)
  - Balance DECIMAL
```

I'm trying to map this data into the following classes:

```
public class Account
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual string Currency { get; private set; }
}

public class SubAccount
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual Account Account { get; private set; }
    public virtual Money Balance { get; private set; }
}
```

The `Money` class looks like:

```
public class Money
{
    public decimal Value { get; private set; }
    public string Currency { get; private set; }
}
```

The part I'm struggling with is where I'm trying to map the *SubAccount.Balance* and *Account.Currency* values into the `SubAccount.Balance` `Money` object.

My mapping classes (below) do the majority of the work but I can't figure out how to build up the `Balance` object using the *Balance* value from the *SubAccount* table and the *Currency* value from the *Account* table.

```
public class AccountMap : ClassMap<Account>
{
    public AccountMap()
    {
        Table("Account");

        Id(x => x.Id)
            .Column("AccountId");
        Map(x => x.Currency)
            .Column("Currency");
    }
}

public class SubAccountMap : ClassMap<SubAccount>
{
    public SubAccountMap()
    {
        Table("SubAccount");

        Id(x => x.Id)
            .Column("AccountId");
        References(x => x.Account)
            .Column("AccountId");

        Component(x => x.Balance,
            m =>
            {
                m.Map(y => y.Value)
                    .Column("Balance");

                m.Map(y => y.Currency)
                    .Column("Account.Currency"); // <-- This is where I get stuck
            });
    }
}
```

Is what I'm trying to do at all possible using Fluent nHibernate?

Comment: FYI, you'd better have your currency not as a string type but a separate table. Then there'll be no unnecessary duplicates of Currency value in your Account entity.

Comment: A join (http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-join) would be helpful in your case but unfortunately it is most likely not allowed to be used within component. Is it possible to modify your db. schema?

Comment: Not really possible to modify the schema in the near future. I tried playing around with the joins but found, as you mentioned, that it didn't allow this kind of configuration using the component functionality.

Answer (score 2):

i dont think its possible, but for a workaround:

```
public class SubAccount
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual Account Account { get; private set; }
    protected virtual decimal Value { get; set; }
    public virtual Money Balance { get { return new Money(Value, Account.Currency); } }
}

public class SubAccountMap : ClassMap<SubAccount>
{
    public SubAccountMap()
    {
        Table("SubAccount");

        Id(x => x.Id)
            .Column("AccountId");
        References(x => x.Account)
            .Column("AccountId");

        Map(Reveal.Property<decimal>("Value"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea - I've got a similar workaround at the moment with the only difference being that I cache the result.

It'll be a bit annoying if this kind of configuration isn't possible, makes things messier than I'd like.